# encoding video for html5 playback

Tags: html, html5-video

I am creating a video portfolio website with a large quantity of videos and I am wondering as to the best way to go about encoding the videos for web playback.  I am using the html5 video for everybody methodology, so I need the video encoded in the following 3 formats:

- h.264
- Ogg
- WebM

I don't necissarily NEED WebM, but it would be nice.

Up until now I've been using a combination of Handbrake and ffmpeg2theora, but I am looking for some sort of all in one solution, as Handbrake seems to have trouble with large sized videos, and ffmpeg2theora is just a pain in the ass.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) works really well for all those formats.

It's essentially a wrapper UI for ffmpeg and has limited options but does a good job.

You can also display the ffmpeg command log and tweak the command if the default output doesn't satisfy you.

It's also free.

Comment: Miro is great, but wondering if there are also some APIs to automate encoding

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [VLC's](http://www.videolan.org) conversion functionality.  It can export in a number of different formats using export plug-ins, and has a handy encoding queue as well.  As of right now I know it can do H.264 as well as Theora ... I'm not sure about WebM ... my version doesn't, but there may be an encoding plug-in coming that will do that as well.

Best of all, VLC is free.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Answer (score 1):

FYI I tried Miro, and ran into some odd conversion issues. My .ogg files were fine, but my .webm files were a bit wonky. They'd play/run fine locally, but I'd get an error with the file when I uploaded it to my server (it would play once, and then hang every time thereafter).

I had some luck with [Firefogg](http://firefogg.org/), which I ended up using without problems.

However, both Miro and Firefogg are more of a one file, click, convert approach. If you're wanting to do a large batch, here's a guide that a friend sent to me, from Brett Terpstra: [Automating HTML5 Video Encodes](http://brettterpstra.com/automating-html5-video-encodes/). It's way over my head... but perhaps of some use to you.